# Using cat to modify ~/.bash_profile seems to remove __git_ps1 compeltely

Tags: shell, here-document

I want my prompt to display the current git-branch when inside of a repo directory. 
e.g.,

```
[desktop repo(master)]$
```

In my terminal I can type:

```
cat <<EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\][\h \W\[\e[m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\[\e[0;32m\]]\$ \[\e[m\]'
EOF
```

But the resultant appended text in .bash_profile is:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\][\h \W\[\e[m\]\[\e[0;32m\]]$ \[\e[m\]'
```

the __git_ps1 method is not present in the result. If I manually edit the .bash_profile with vim then source ~./bash_profile, the PS1 statement contains the __git_ps1 method and it works fine.

This cat statement is part of a larger 'bootstrapping' script, but I've trimmed out all the irrelevant stuff. I have successfully implemented this on Ubuntu. I am trying to get it running on a CentOS VM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cat << "EOF"`, this prevents expansion of the dollar function and the quotes.

Comment: yep. that was it. huzzah!